# Match the Combination

Tags: logical-deduction

A Number Lock has 3 digit key. `###`
that should fulfil the following conditions:

**`6 8 2` - One Number is well placed and correct.

`6 1 4` - One Number is correct but wrong placed.

`2 0 6` - Two Numbers are correct but wrong placed.

`7 3 8` - Nothing is correct.

`7 8 0` - One Number is correct but wrong placed.**

Can you crack the code ?

Answer (score 1):

> 0 4 2

Because

> One of `6 8 2` is correct and the right spot. By the second line, we can eliminate `6`, which didn't change position, but would now have to be in the wrong spot. By the 5th line, we eliminate `8`, as well. This means that the code is `x x 2`.
>  The third line tells us that `0` is in the code, but not in the middle or last position. The code is now `0 x 2`. Neither of these numbers appears in the second line, which indicates that either `1` or `4` is correct, but not in the right spot. The only one of these two not in the middle is `4`, therefore, the code is `0 4 2`.

Answer (score 1):

> 042

because:

> 4 tells us no 7,3,8, therefore by 5, 0 is in it. 3 tells us 0 is first. 1 then tells us 2 is last. 3 tells us 6 isn't in it, and 2 tells us 4 is in the middle.